# How to perform a segue by tapping a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I wonder if it is possible to conenct a `UIView` property to a UIViewController. By connecting a `UIView`, I want to transition to a second view controller. I have attempted several times by dragging and coding, but I just faild. I am looking for ways that do not need to program like using seague.

Is there anything that achievs this goal?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean with "connect"?

Comment: like `.addSubview`` ?

Comment: So I want to transition to a second view controller by clicking a UIView. @DavidSeek

Comment: i have created the code for you. with explanation comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To perform a segue by tapping a `UIView`, you need to add a gesture recognizer. In my example I instantiate and added a `Subclass` of `UIView` programmatically :

```
viewDidLoad(){

    // here we instantiate an object of our subclass
    let customView = MyViewSubclass(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    // here we add it to our ViewController
    self.view.addSubview(customView)

    // here we instantiate an object of gesture recognizer
    let gestureRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.someAction (_:)))
    // here we add it to our custom view
    customView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRec)
}

func someAction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){     
   performSegueWithIdentifier("Whazzzzup", sender: self)
}

// Swift 3
func someAction(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){  

   // this is the function that lets us perform the segue   
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "Whazzzup", sender: self)
}
```

If you don't have a `Subclass` of `UIView`, then you just add a `UIView`...

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
```

Also you could of course just take your `UIView` Outlet and add the gesture recognizer to it.

```
let gestureRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.someAction (_:)))
myView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRec)
```

To present a `ViewController` **without segue**, you need to instantiate the ViewController:

```
func someAction(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
    self.present(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    // swift 2
    // self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You need to set the `withIdentifier` in your ViewController's Attribute Inspector:

[image]

In this example `withIdentifier` would be: LandingVC

If you're using a `UINavigationController` and want a `back Button`, you push the `ViewController` on the Navigation stack:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller!, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks! But it is not working now because I am not implementing this well. Where should I set the identifier to? I prepared a UITableVIewControoler and attached a call name to the identifier section. Is this correct? If not, what does the identifier refer to?

Comment: see my edit. you need to set a storyboard id for your controller and set it as `withIdentifier`

Comment: Wonderful!!!!!!!!!!!!! This is working!!!!! I have been struggling with the identifier but I carefully looked at the picture you provided and I only looked at the class name, so I left storyboard id section blank! I appreciate your help and efforts into this. Big thanks!

Comment: you're welcome bro. and you should accept my question edit. might prevent you from receiving further downvotes

Comment: My English is not fluent but I am practicing it here as well. Your language correction is hugly helpful. Thank you so much again!!

Answer (score 9):

Storyboard mode supports this (at least now.)   Drag a Tap Gesture Recognizer onto your view you want to click.   Then connect the gesture recognizer to the view you want to show, just like any other segue transition.  Make sure any containing views are "User Interaction Enabled."   No code required.
[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW14)